# Raspberry Pi as ibeacon reaceiver and transmitter

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to use raspi 3 as ibeacon transmitter and receiver. I want to transmit and receive unique id,major id and minor id. However,it says I would need a bluetooth 4.0 usb for this. If raspi 3 has inbuilt bluetooth why would I require external modem for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi 3 comes loaded with a Bluetooth 4.1 module. It should work fine.

I'm going to put my psychic hat on and presume that you're reading [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview) on Adafruit. That looks to have been written to be as widely applicable as possible, and to sell large quantities of [Adafruit's own USB Bluetooth module](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1327), which is heavily linked throughout. Because only the Pi 3 has built-in Bluetooth it's likely just easier to provide universal instructions that work on every Pi.